# TFS Admin Console missing Build Configuration Node

Tags: tfs

I've been forced to reinstall the TFS build service on one of our build machines, and after I uninstalled and reinstalled, the Build Configuration node does not get loaded in the Team Foundation Server Administrative Console. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling a couple of times without success. The build service is running fine, with 2 agents.

It's TFS2010.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A developer from TFS Admin & Ops team suggested the following:

> Any chance the TFS Power Tools were installed on that box?  There was
>   a problem with the backup power tool that caused some nodes not to
>   show up. If that’s the case, under
>   HKLM\Software\Microsoft\TeamFoundationServer\10.0\Plugins there will
>   probably be two nodes – one for backup and one for TeamBuild –
>   removing the backup plug-in node would probably resolve the problem. 
>   You could also check the admin log to see if there are exceptions in
>   there, and perhaps export the TFS registry key above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep - TFSPT is installed - I'll try the reg. hack and see if it works.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks ...again! Can I get direct phone number for TFS support? ;)

Comment: Thank you very much! :)  This worked perfectly on Windows Server 2008 x64, the TFS Admin Console just needed to be relaunched; a reboot is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In my case build services were not installed at all on the machine with TFS app tier and build controller configuration was available from the separate build server.